# Android Google map application crashes while changing activity

Tags: android, crash

I all. I'm working on an android Google map application. The application use Mapview to show Google map. The main activity displays Google map and an overlay at startup. On a long press event i call another form which i'm using as context menu since i'm unable to get context menu on Google maps. This form again calls another form on click of button. Please find the code i'm using below. The code crashes at StartActivity() function while calling Item activity which shows the menu. Please help.

```
////////////////////////////////MainActivity.java code/////////////////////////////

package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Exception;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity
{
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;
    public Intent myIntent;

    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        long startTime;
        long endTime;
        float startX, startY, endX, endY;

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                  

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);           
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-35, null);



            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
        {  

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //record the start time
                startTime = event.getEventTime();
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();

            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                //record the end time
                endTime = event.getEventTime();
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
            }

             //verify
            if(((endTime - startTime) > 1000) && (startX == endX) && (startY == endY))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Opening menu!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myIntent = new Intent(mapView.getContext(), Item.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent("net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Item");
                    //myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    //myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    //startActivity(myIntent);

                    //Context context = net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.getBaseContext();
                    //context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Item.class));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("Events", e.getMessage());
                }
                return true; //notify that you handled this event (do not propagate)
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        switch (keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                mc.zoomIn();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                mc.zoomOut();
                break;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        String coordinates[] = {"12.966667", "77.566667"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6),
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17);

      //---Add a location marker---
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////Item.java code/////////////////////////////

package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Item extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_menu);

        Button pavement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pavement);
        pavement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Pavement.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                //startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Pavement"));
            }
        });
    }

}


///////////////////////////////////Pavement.java code////////////////////

package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Pavement extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.pavement_menu);       
    }
}

/////////////////////////////../layout/item_menu.xml code////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/pavment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pavment"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

////////////////////////////../layout/main.xml code////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TableRow >
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0eXLh5uOHzxYyO-UUL3iRgxeYZoGeY7yusL32zA"
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

/////////////////////////////../layout/menu.xml code://///////////////////////


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    >
    <item android:id="@+id/pavement"
        android:title="Pavement" />
    <item android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:title="Sign" />
</menu>

////////////////////////../layout/pavement_menu.xml code//////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/viewInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View info"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/enterSurvey"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter survey"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

/////////////////////////////////AndroidManifest.xml///////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MapsActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Item"
            android:label="Item"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Pavement"
            android:label="Pavement"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"


</manifest>
```

//////////////////////////////LogCat////////////////////////////////

```
12-06 17:48:47.457: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 183K, 3% free 10221K/10503K, paused 7ms+11ms
12-06 17:48:47.457: W/CursorWrapperInner(636): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-06 17:48:47.468: W/CursorWrapperInner(636): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-06 17:48:47.689: D/gralloc_goldfish(636): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-06 17:48:48.437: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 4% free 10548K/10887K, paused 6ms+5ms
12-06 17:48:49.597: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 5% free 10710K/11207K, paused 6ms+8ms
12-06 17:48:50.907: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 411K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 8ms+6ms
12-06 17:48:52.178: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 6ms+13ms
12-06 17:48:53.568: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 9ms+15ms
12-06 17:48:54.798: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 6ms+6ms
12-06 17:48:55.968: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 6ms+13ms
12-06 17:48:57.257: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10704K/11335K, paused 6ms+8ms
12-06 17:48:58.457: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 6ms+10ms
12-06 17:48:59.608: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10704K/11335K, paused 6ms+12ms
12-06 17:49:02.808: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10705K/11335K, paused 6ms+6ms
12-06 17:49:04.587: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 6% free 10709K/11335K, paused 8ms+6ms
12-06 17:49:06.237: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10710K/11335K, paused 11ms+6ms
12-06 17:49:07.787: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10710K/11335K, paused 6ms+7ms
12-06 17:49:09.380: D/dalvikvm(636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 6% free 10710K/11335K, paused 6ms+6ms
12-06 17:49:10.208: D/AndroidRuntime(636): Shutting down VM
12-06 17:49:10.208: W/dalvikvm(636): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Item}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Item.onCreate(Item.java:17)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-06 17:49:10.248: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please don't just post all your code, in the future. Post the exception stack trace from logcat and the relevant code

Comment: Your code works fine in my eclipse.. without any exception..

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what happen,

In **class MapOverlay**

```
 myIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Item.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
```

or

```
 myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Item.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
```

And in **Item class**

```
 public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Item.this, Pavement.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                //startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.Pavement"));
            }
```

Comment: I think that this will solve your problem, but if it dont you can always use onTouchEvent method in your class MapsActivity...

Comment: @Jovan - yes, You can use onTouchEvent in MapsActivity but here I suggested him to only make changes to his existing code.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried it, but it didn't work. Now, even the AVD is not getting launched.

Comment: @user370305 - yes, i saw what you did, but i wanted to tell him that he have and other possibilitys..Can you put your LOGCAT???

Comment: What's the line 17 in Item.java class?

Comment: Line 17 it Item.java class is :         pavement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Pavement.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
             
            }

Comment: Now whats the error? This time I think you have a got different error.

Comment: App still crashes... Edited my post with new LogCat details.